# How do I send data from a controler to a view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple controller that was created through a scaffold and has a "Show" function.

In the view that was created through the scaffold, I have an image that appears only on a certain condition.

I want to set or evaluate the condition in the controller and send it to the view.
I am not sure how to do that or whether this is the correct approach.

Comment: I suggest that you read "Agile web development with rails", it has this (and many other things) covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition should generally be dealt with in the view file using erb, or haml. If you update your question with the condition, then I'll see about updating my answer to reflect it. For now, I'll use a common condition.

Say you only want to show an image if an object is featured. Let's imagine there is a featured field in your object that acts as a flag (1,0).

If this object is say an Article, we can then check the condition in the view file. The controller would obtain the article from the model:

```
-# articles_controller show action 
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

..

```
-# views/articles/show.html.erb
<% if @article.featured? %>
  // show image here
<% end %>
```

Remember this is an example condition that is not necessarily correct. It is just to illustrate my initial approach.

I wouldn't suggest you use javascript to hide/show depending on this condition, because you are then putting your logic in javascript, when it can be easily managed from within your view files.

If the condition is complex, you would then move it to the model, and perform something like:

```
if @article.some_complex_condition?
```

..rather than having that complex condition in your controller file. This allows you to reuse the condition away from the specific controller and makes it more testable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show and hide an image based on a certain condition, than you can do that with **JQuery**.  You shouldn't put anything in the controller that is view-centric.

You can also get the id of whatever data element is in 'show' and pass it to the JavaScript.

JQuery has `show()` and `hide()` methods that would work for you.  Here's the documentation on the hide method:  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Basically, if you had a certain id for your image, you'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myImage").hide();

  if (some_condition === true) {
    $("#myImage").show();
  }
});
```

You can put that code in your `application.js` file.

I whipped up a simple JsFiddle demonstrating a way to show and hide with buttons:
http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/92RDS/

Of course, the code may be different depending on what you are trying to do.

If you need to get the 'id' of the object in the 'show' view, than you can put a script tag at the bottom of your show view like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_show_object = <%= @some_object.id %>  //this will be the specific id of whatever the object is that you passed from the controller
  alert(my_show_object);  //this helps with debugging to see if you have the right id
</script>
```

If you need more than the id, and you want to get the entire Rails object and represent it as Javascript - just do this at the bottom of your rails 'show' view:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">               
    var my_object = <%= @your_rails_object.to_json %>;     
    console.log(my_object); //This code allows you to look in the console and see exactly what your object looks like.
 </script>
```

Just like the last one, `@your_rails_object` is the variable that you have in your           show view in the controller.  This will return it as a json object so that you can get the id or whatever properties it has.

Also, if you are just learning Rails, I would recommend this online book: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

That's how I learned Rails - the book is **excellent** and **free**.